# How is exit status passed between pthread_exit and pthread_join? Is a correction needed in man page?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Question:

How exactly is exit status passed between pthread_exit and pthread_join?

From [pthread_join man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)

```
   int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

> If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the exit status of
>          the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to
>          pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by *retval.  If the
>          target thread was canceled, then PTHREAD_CANCELED is placed in
>          *retval.

I think the wording in the man page is incorrect.

It should be "If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the address of the variable holding the exit status of the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to
       pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by retval."

I wrote this code that shows this, see code comments:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void * function(void*);

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int arg = 991;
    int * status; // notice I did not intialize status, status is *retval
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, function, (void*)(&arg));

    pthread_join(thread, (void **)(&status));//passing address of status,&status is retval 

    //(2) this address is same as printed in (1)
    printf("The address of returned status is %p,", status); 

    printf("The returned status is %d\n", *status);
}

void * function(void * arg)
{
    int *p;
    p = (int*)arg;
    printf("I am in thread.\n");

     //(1) printing the address of variable holding the exit status of thread, see (2)                                                              
    printf("The arg address is %p %p\n", p, arg); 

    pthread_exit(arg);
}
```

***Sample o/p:***

I am in thread.

The arg address is 0xbfa64878 0xbfa64878

The address of returned status is 0xbfa64878,The returned status is 991***

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: The exit status *is* a void pointer. It is *not* (necessarily) the address of anything.

Comment: @stakx I added a question. I thought my question was implicit but now I added an explicit question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't contradict the man page.

> If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the exit status of the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by *retval.

You call `pthread_join` with `retval=&status`, so it's not NULL.

You called `pthread_exit(0xbfa64878)` so the exit status of the target thread is `0xbfa64878` and that gets copied into `*retval` i.e. `status = 0xbfa64878`, which is what you print out.

I think you're confusing things with labels such as "address of returned status" and "arg address" ... you're giving labels to the values which pthreads doesn't imply. What the man page says is that `*retval` gets set to the value passed to `pthread_exit` and that's what your test shows.

In your proposed change:

> If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the address of the variable holding the exit status of the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by retval.

What is "the variable holding the exit status of the target thread"?  Pthreads defines no such thing.  The exit status of the target thread **is the value passed to `pthread_exit`**, it's not the value of some other variable.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the exit status of the target thread is the value passed to pthread_exit, it's not the value of some other variable. I was thinking that the exit status has to an int value and that it cannot be an address. But that not right. Correct?

Comment: Wait, there is a problem still. "into the location pointed to by *retval." implies *retval has an address and the exit status is copied as the value at that address. But what is happening is that the exit status is being copied into *retval itself and not the location pointed to by *retval.It should say: "into the location pointed to by retval." because retval is a void ** and the exit status is void *. That would be correct I believe.

Comment: Hey Jon what do you think of my comment just above this comment? Please let me know.

Comment: Your first comment is definitely correct, the exit status is a `void*` not an `int`. I think your second comment is correct too, it should say _"into the location pointed to by `retval`."_ or just _"into `*retval`."_